# DataFrame row and previous row calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df as such:

```
ID      Category      Event_Time
A          X              12:00
B          X              12:05
B          X              12:05
C          X              12:08
D          X              12:10
D          X              12:10        
E          Y              12:15
```

I'm trying to calculate the difference between event times of current ID and previous ID. For Example:

```
ID      Category      Event_Time    Difference
A          X              12:00         NA
B          X              12:05        :05
B          X              12:05        :05
C          X              12:08        :03
D          X              12:10        :02
D          X              12:10        :02 
E          Y              12:15         NA
```

There's a few catches. In order for the difference to take place, the Categories between row operations must match.In addition, there's the situation of multiple lines with the same ID and thus same Event_Time, but the difference between the previous ID must still be calculated.

I have a for loop that basically goes like this:

```
unique_id = df.ID.unique()
difference_dict = {}
for i in range (1,len(unique_ID)):
   if current category = previous category
        difference = event_time[i] - event_time[i-1]
    else:
        difference = na
    difference_dict[unique_id[i]] = difference
```

Employing a data dict to store the info for now.

I'm finding that the for loop is quite slow, does anybody have a more robust solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` to remove the duplicates per ID, then use `Series.diff` to get the difference. Finally we forwardfill (`ffill`):

```
# convert Event_Time to datetime, so we can make calculations
df['Event_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event_Time'])

categorys = df['Category'].shift().eq(df['Category'])
df['Difference'] = df.drop_duplicates('ID')['Event_Time'].diff()
df['Difference'] = df.groupby('Category')['Event_Time'].ffill().where(categorys)

# get Event_Time back in correct format
df['Event_Time'] = df['Event_Time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')

  ID Category Event_Time          Difference
0  A        X      12:00                 NaT
1  B        X      12:05 2020-04-28 12:05:00
2  B        X      12:05 2020-04-28 12:05:00
3  C        X      12:08 2020-04-28 12:08:00
4  D        X      12:10 2020-04-28 12:10:00
5  D        X      12:10 2020-04-28 12:10:00
6  E        Y      12:15                 NaT
```

Comment: This is a good start, but doesn't account for the different categories of events. Perhaps one could seperate the dataframe into individual dataframes for each category first, run this method, and then rejoin?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "different categories". If you mean each group of `ID`, it does take that into account

Comment: It doesnt drop the duplicates actually. Thats just a temporary step to calculate the difference. Check the output @Steel

Comment: The Categories rule ensures that the difference can only take place on rows with the same categories. In your example, line 6 should have a Difference of NA since it's category is Y and the previous is X.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, didnt understand correctly. Edited my code accordingly. This should work.

Comment: Forgot to add `categorys` variable, dont forget to copy that as well @Steel